# Boost::Thread access violation when calling join

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, join

I'm having some problems attempting to create a multi-threaded Server. Everything works fine until I need to remove a client from the server.

The server is run in it's own thread, then each client has it's own thread as well.

I'm using boost::thread for all the threads. When I need to stop the client I call

```
void StopClient()
{
    assert(mThread);

    mStopMutex.lock();
    mStopRequested = true;
    mStopMutex.unlock();

    shutdown(mSocket,2);

    mThread->join();
}
```

Adding a breakpoint to the line

```
shutdown(mSocket,2);
```

I can see that mThread doesn't exist! Does this mean that the thread has already exited? Do you always need to call join() for a boost::thread?

If I allow the code to run I get an access violation error.

**Update**

ServerThread

```
void StartServer() 
{
    assert(!mListenThread);
    mListenThread = boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread>(new boost::thread(boost::bind(&ServerThread::Listen, this)));
    mUpdateThread = boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread>(new boost::thread(boost::bind(&ServerThread::Update, this)));
}

void StopServer()
{
    assert(mListenThread);
    mStopRequested = true;

            mMutex.lock();
            for(int i = 0; i < mClients.size(); i++ )
                mClients[i]->StopClient();
            mMutex.unlock();

    mListenThread->join();
}

void Listen()
{
    while (!mStopRequested)
    {
        std::cout << "Waiting for connection" << std::endl;         
        if(mClientSocket = accept( mServerSocket, (sockaddr*) &mServerAddr, &addrlen ) )
        {
            mMutex.lock();
            if( mClients.size() > 0 )
            {
                for( int i = 0; i < mClients.size(); i++ )
                {
                    if( mClients[i]->getClientSocket() != mClientSocket )
                    {
                        ClientThread newClient;
                        newClient.Initialise(mClientSocket);
                        mClients.push_back(&newClient);
                        mClients[mClients.size()-1]->StartClient();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ClientThread newClient;
                newClient.Initialise(mClientSocket);
                mClients.push_back(&newClient);
                mClients[mClients.size()-1]->StartClient();
            }
            mMutex.unlock();
        }
    }
}          

void Update()
{
    while (!mStopRequested)
    {
        mMutex.lock();

        std::cout << "::::Server is updating!::::" << mClients.size() << std::endl;
        for( int i = 0; i< mClients.size(); i++ )
        {
            if( !mClients[i]->IsActive() )
            {
                mClients[i]->StopClient();
                mClients.erase( mClients.begin() + i );
            }
        }

        mMutex.unlock();

    }
}
```

ClientThread

```
void StartClient()
{
    assert(!mThread);
    mThread = boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread>(new boost::thread(boost::bind(&ClientThread::Update, this)));
}

void Update()
{
    bool stopRequested;
    do
    {
        mStopMutex.lock();
        stopRequested = mStopRequested;
        mStopMutex.unlock();

        std::cout << "lol" << std::endl;
        if( mTimeOut < 1000 )
        {
            mTimeOut++;
        }
        else
        {
            mActive = false;
        }

        boost::this_thread::interruption_point();
    }
    while( !stopRequested);
}
```

Comment: You need to show us more code than that. Where is `mThread` set, and to what value? Where else is it used?

Comment: What do you mean with "mThread doesn't exist"? Is it NULL or does it point to a deleted object?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I've updated to show some more code! @Rüdiger it just points to a deleted object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            ClientThread newClient;
            newClient.Initialise(mClientSocket);
            mClients.push_back(&newClient);
```

This creates a local variable on the stack, and puts the address of it into your list of mClients.  Then the scope ends, and so does the local variable.  This leaves your list `mClients` pointing at something that's not there anymore.

Comment: That's a good point!
I've changed the code to 

`ClientThread* newClient = new ClientThread();
newClient->Initialise(mClientSocket);
mClients.push_back(newClient);`


and now it works! :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough code here to determine exactly what's going on, but here are things to check:

- You likely have a processing loop within your client thread that is checking the mStopRequested member.  Before the processing loop exits, is it changing the mThread member?
- Is mThread NULL when you get the access violation? Or, is it some other value?  Is it valid before setting mStopRequested to true?